# Разбор POST запросов в Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

1. Открываю ручками `Google Chrome`
2. Перехожу на сайт
3. Открываю по `F12` `Dev Tools`
4. Перехожу на вкладку `Console`
5. Выполняю `JavaScript` функцию которая существует на этом сайте
6. При выполнении функции отправляется `POST` запрос и приходит `Response`
7. Перехожу на вкладку `Network` и забираю `Response`

**Вопрос**

Как с помощью `Selenium` выполнить 6-7 пункт ?

Т.е. мне нужно просто забрать значение `Response` из `POST` запроса который отправляется после выполнения `JavaScript` функции

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("сайт");
driver.ExecuteScript("скрипт");

// Как следить за выполняющимися запросами ?
```

Comment: `string result = driver.ExecuteScript("скрипт();") as string;` или `string result = driver.ExecuteAsyncScript("var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1]; var result = await скрипт(); callback(result);") as string;`

Comment: @aepot Wow!!! - 2е то что нужно. Спасибо большое. Надо теперь разобраться как это работает xD

Comment: Помните, что Selenium - это инструмент тестирования, а не автоматизации парсинга. Если вам нужен парсинг, то научитесь анализировать ресурс, смотреть как он взаимодействует с сервером, какие запросы отправляются, а уже затем эмулируйте эту работу сами. В 90% случаев Selenium не нужен вовсе, а тянуть с собой целый браузер лишь для того, чтобы отправить несколько POST запросов - это как на танке в магазин через дорогу ездить...